# Is there any way to upload a folder(have subfolders also) instead of file using .netcore web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Is it possible to upload the entire folder with same folder structure using .netcore webapi. I know we can zip and upload, then unzip, just wondering for alternative way to upload as it is instead of zipping

Currently i have updated the controller as below, this logic doesnot consider folders for upload

```
    private async Task<bool> Import()
    {
        bool isSaveSuccess = false;
        string fileName;
        var files = Request.Form.Files;
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            try
            {
                var extn = "." + file.FileName.Split('.')[file.FileName.Split('.').Length - 1];
                fileName = file.FileName + DateTime.Now.Ticks + extn;
                //fileName = Path.Combine(file.FileName, DateTime.Now.Ticks + extn);

                var pathBuilt = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Upload\\files1");

                if (!Directory.Exists(pathBuilt))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(pathBuilt);
                }

                var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Upload\\files1", fileName);

                using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }
                isSaveSuccess = true;
            }
            catch
            {
                _logger.LogError("Request failed: " + "err");

            }
        }
        return isSaveSuccess;
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean like a form upload? Or something more advanced?

Comment: Yup, using form upload i able to get only files( *.* or zip files) but not the folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it should be possible. Have a look at `webkitdirectory` property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/webkitdirectory

This will let you select one or more folders, so you can iterate over the inner contents of the users selection. As you can see, this is a "native" feature and not limited to asp.net or c# in any way.

```html
<input type="file" id="files" name="files" webkitdirectory multiple />
<ul id="listing"></ul>
```

```
document.getElementById("filepicker").addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  let output = document.getElementById("listing");
  let files = event.target.files;

  for (let i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
    let item = document.createElement("li");
    item.innerHTML = files[i].webkitRelativePath;
    output.appendChild(item);
  };
}, false);
```

As you can see from the demo code, you can get the relative path by calling `.webkitRelativePath`, so yit should be no problem to recreate the folder structure on your target.

Be aware, that this feature is not natively available on Internet Explorer and Firefox versions on android below 50.

**Update for saving files with subfolders**

Here is a bare minimum example of uploading taking any number of uploaded form files and saving them to disk, while keeping the relative folder structure.

First change your controllers constructor to get a your current environment in:

```
private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;
public HomeController(IWebHostEnvironment environment)
{
   _env = environment;
}
```

Then amend your upload logic accordingly:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload([FromForm] IFormFileCollection files)
{
   //target in wwwroot for static files
   string targetFolder = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "uploads");
   foreach (IFormFile file in files)
   {
      if (file.Length <= 0) continue;

      //fileName is the the fileName including the relative path
      string path = Path.Combine(targetFolder, file.FileName);

      //check if folder exists, create if not
      var fi = new FileInfo(path);
      fi.Directory?.Create();

      //copy to target
      using var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
      await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
   }
   return View("Index");
}
```

This will result to your folder and all its subfolders being saved into your `wwwroot/uploads/` folder inside your application:

```
wwwroot/
|
|-uploads
        |-MyFolder
                 |- File1.jpg
                 |- File2.jpg
                 |- MyFolder2
                            |- File3.jpg
```

I'd recommend saving them somewhere different though, because redeploying might clean out the application folder first, depending on your deployment strategy (xcopy, github actions, azure pipelines, containers ...)

Comment: Seems like above answer is in java script, what i am looing at is C#(.Netcore 3.1) for my backend. To store the folder in the server

Comment: If you give me a starting point, where you are stuck I'm sure I could come up with something, but your question gave us a blank slate, so my solution picked up at the earliest point a user could do something.

Comment: Sorry for partial information, currently i have written the logic in the controller as above, i have updated my Question

Comment: @Lax I've updated my answer with the missing asp.net core bits,

Comment: thank you very much for the answer, It is exactly what i am looking for. Appreciated! @Marco

Comment: Feel free to click the checkmark next to my answer, to mark your question as solved.